# How to Convert XML Response of a Third-Party Service into JSON in WCF?

Tags: xml, json, wcf, web-services

I am converting a Third-Party Service Response(XML) into JSON format by using JSON.NET.

The Code i have tried so far,

```
   IEnumerable<XElement> xe;
        IEnumerable<XElement> xe1;
        List<XElement> ele = new List<XElement>();

 using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
        {

          XNamespace ns = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05";
          XDocument xd = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

           xe = xd.Root.Descendants(ns + "PricedItineraries").ToList();
            ele = new List<XElement>();

            foreach (XElement b in xe)
            {
                ele.Add(b);
            }
```

}

In above Code, How to convert the ele into JSON format ?
And I have Converted XMLdocument into JSON by using the following way,

```
 Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xdoc);
```

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ele, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);)
```

Comment: It is Converting into JSON. How to remove the Namespace(ns1) of the Nodes?[{\"ns1:PricedItineraries\":{\"ns1:PricedItinerary..

Comment: JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ele, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);) returns like {"SearchRequest1Result":"[\u000d\u000a  {\u000d\u000a    \"ns1:PricedItineraries\": {\u000d\u000a ...